# WinXP Run Command: run CMD as administrator?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, administrator

In the run command dialog, type "cmd.exe". Yet, I wonder how I can run CMD as administrator in a single run command line. (P.S. I know how to do it with the mouse, so just asking a command line to achieve so). Thank you!

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true ?

Comment: A good reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do it from `.bat` file:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment

    @echo off
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %*
    exit /b 0

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

  var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var args=WScript.Arguments;
  var filename=args.Item(0);

  var shell=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");




  shell.ShellExecute(filename,"","","runas",1);
```

it's just a raw script that uses [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx)  .But I'm afraid that the UAC pop-up is unskipable. Other option is to create a shortcut that has [`run as Administrator`](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1897) check but again there will be pop-up.